# Bootstrap Left Tab not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the left tab nav the same way that is in the boilerplate, with all the necessary resources, but the tabs aren't switching when the links are clicked:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"> <a href="#lA" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a> 
        </li>
        <li class=""> <a href="#lB" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a>

        </li>
        <li class=""> <a href="#lC" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="lA">
            <p>Section A.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="lB">
            <p>Section B.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="lC">
            <p>Section C.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is with the `id` values. Change `1A` to `A1` and so on..

Comment: [This is working for me in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/rtpHarry/CwtVC/) - Do you have a working url that we can see if there is another javascript exception occurring?

Comment: @karthikr id values are arbitrary, as long as they match up.

Comment: As @rtpHarry said, this should be working. I'm guessing something is going wrong in javascript. Can you double check how you're importing the bootstrap js file? And check the dev tools console for any javascript errors?

Comment: matt, re @karthikr thats true if you are working in html5 but before [id's had start with a-z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score -1):

A JS reference link wasn't complete.